# Amateur Bicycle Racing outside of the US

Tags: regional, racing, travelling, europe

I'm interested in taking a trip to Europe (although perhaps this question can apply to other areas of the world) and do some bike racing at a really amateur level like the equivalent of Cat 4 or Cat 3 in the US.  Mainly interested in road races.

Any ideas on where I can find information on these types of races if they exist?  Also any tips on administrative details of racing as a foreigner are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are coming to the Uk then the [British Cycling](http://www.britishcycling.org.uk/) website is probably the place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the website of the national cycling federation in your country of interest should point you in the right direction in terms of races. Finding a local club should help you immensely as well.

I believe that in most places you can race with either a local license or an international (UCI) license. Depending on where you live and where you're planning to race, one of those options may be considerably cheaper than the other (North American licenses tend to be cheaper than those in western Europe, for example).

Answer (score 0):

In the UK, TLI Cycling events offer age-related racing, allowing a rider to compete in his/her peer group, without paying over the top for a UCI licence. TLI Cycling offers single day membership at £4 on top of the race entry fee, and provides you with public liability insurance of £10,000,000.

For details see the [TLI Cycling](http://www.tlicycling.org.uk) website

Comment: Dunno why this got a downvote - you're totally right to bring up the question of insurance.   I doubt travel insurance covers any sort of organised racing.